# _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) Error

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator

I encoutered an error "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" at the last line of the code below:

```
pixelCoorindateAndThreePoint* tempSpace = new pixelCoorindateAndThreePoint[possibleMaxSize];
while (sscanf(temp, "%f %f", &cam1x, &cam1y)){
    location = (int)(file->length*cam1y + cam1x);
    file->cam1cam2ThreeDPoints[(int)(file->length*cam1y + cam1x)] = new pixelCoorindateAndThreePoint;
        sscanf(temp, "%*f %*f %f %f %f %f %f \n",
            &(tempSpace->PixelCoordinateCam2.x),
            &(tempSpace->PixelCoordinateCam2.y),
            &(tempSpace->threePoints.x),
            &(tempSpace->threePoints.y),
            &(tempSpace->threePoints.z));

        file->cam1cam2ThreeDPoints[location] = tempSpace;
        tempSpace++;

    temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
    delete[] tempSpace;
```

Why I get such an error? Since I have copy those pointer value to `file->cam1cam2ThreeDPoints`, I should be able to delete `tempSpace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`tempSpace++;`* changes the pointer. You need to remember the originally allocated pointer for calling `delete` with it.

Comment: Or better still, don't use `new`.  In this case, use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks. I get it. Will accept your answer after 5 minutes

Comment: @Martin Bonner Thanks for your suggestion.